# SharePoint List Item Not Returning Fields

Tags: sharepoint, list

Hi I have a question about SPListItem and how to retrieve values from it.  In the view I am in I can access the "Article" no problem but when I try to access the "Link" I can an error saying object not initalized.  I don't understand whats going on?  Why can I not get the Link when I can get the Article field.  Here is the code I am using:

```
SPList myList = eachWeb.Lists["Listings"];
SPListItemCollection myItemCollection = myList.GetItems(myList.Views["Active Announcements"]);
for (int i = 0; i < myItemCollection.Count; i++)
{
SPListItem realitem = myItemCollection[i]; 
writer.Write(realitem["Article"].ToString()+"<BR>"); // Works without the bottom line
writer.Write(realitem["Link"].ToString()+"<BR>");  // Causes error
```

My view contains a column for both Article and Link.  Thank you.

Comment: Now I get the error "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: Try debugging and looking through the names of the fields.

Answer (score 3):

The internal name of a field may not match the display name; especially if you've changed the name after creating the list. Try debugging and taking a look at the names of the fields in the `SPListItemCollection` and see if you can figure out which one it is there.

Comment: How can I call by the internal IE)
what is realitem["Article"] calling?  is it the internal or display name?

Comment: You're always using the internal name to get the item, and in some cases the real name will match the display name. This is not always the case - for example, I have a field in my list that displays 'Title' when I view the list, but its internal name is 'Name'.

Comment: the ListItem.Fields.SchemaXML property returns the underlying item XML.  It contains the DisplayName & Internal Name.